# MASTER-MASTER replication failed on Production: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s)

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I'm not DBA but under my responsiblity to fix this issue. cause we are small company

I need help to fix this issue
could not find related issue on forums

### ERROR occured after I was importing dump DB to master1

Plz guide me to fix this issue

I tried this SOLUTION method:

`mysqlbinlog --read-from-remote-server -h 10.145.160.26 -u replica1 node2-bin.000040 --verbose --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS -p|grep -A10 -B10 345612577` but I got empty output

ERROR:

**MASTER1 error:**

```
Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master                           log node1-bin.000018, end_log_pos 594107483. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
```

**MASTER2 error:**

```
Last_SQL_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master                           log node2-bin.000040, end_log_pos 168239245. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
```

**Master1:**

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| node2-bin.000051 | 434103214 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

**Master2:**

```
show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| node1-bin.000042 |  1451131 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

my configs.

```
[mysqld]

server-id=2
replicate-same-server-id=0
auto-increment-increment=2
auto-increment-offset=2
relay-log=/var/lib/mysql/node2-relay-bin
relay-log-index=/var/lib/mysql/node2-relay-bin.index
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql.error
master-info-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-master.info
relay-log-info-file=/var/lib/mysql/node1-relay-log.info
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/node2-bin
max_connections = 1000

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: @J.D. 
I got this output on quesry you mentioned--



Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log node1-bin.000018, end_log_pos 594107878; Error 'Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'client_potential_meganet_agreements_client_id_foreign'' on query. Default database: 'netcore_support'. Query: 'ALTER TABLE `client_potential_meganet_agreements`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `client_potential_meganet_agreements_client_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client_potential_meganet` (`id`)'